# Problemas en con primos, amigos,perfectos, y arrays

Tags: java, array, booleano

La verdad es que me mareé, y me estaría funcionando solamente amigos, si me pueden ayudar seria genial.

La idea del ejercicio es que el usuario diga la cantidad de elementos que va a utilizar, los números del vector, si en esa lista hay números primos, si hay perfectos, y si hay amigos, perfecto no está, lo saqué, pero mi problema empieza en números primos y en cantidad de elementos.

Muchas gracias.

```
public class Numero  {

    private static Scanner lector;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Ingresar cantidad de elementos: ");
        //String num=lector.nextLine();
        //int[] elementos = convertirListaSeparadaPorComaEnArrayDeEnteros(num);
        System.out.println("Ingresar numeros del vector: ");
        String num1 = lector.nextLine();
        int[] vector = convertirListaSeparadaPorComaEnArrayDeEnteros(num1);
        System.out.println("Ingresar otro numero: ");
        String num2 = lector.nextLine();
        int[] vector2 = convertirListaSeparadaPorComaEnArrayDeEnteros(num2);
        System.out.println("Resultado:");
        //mostrarElementos(elementos);
        ordenarNumeros(vector);
        mostrarPrimo(vector);
        //mostrarPerfecto (vector);
        mostrarAmigo(vector,vector2);
    }

    static void  mostrarPrimo(int[] vector) {
        int n = vector.length;
        int contador = 0;
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1 ; i++) {
                if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7) {
                    System.out.println("Es primo: " + i);
                }
                if (i % 2 != 0 && i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0 && i % 7 != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Es primo: "+i);
                }
            }
            contador++;
        } while (contador <= 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor revisa [ask]. ¿Cuál es el problema específico que tienes con tu código?

Answer (score 0):

Solución de números primos:

```
static void  mostrarPrimo(int[] vector) {
        int n = vector.length;
        
        // ciclo para recorrer los números del vector
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            // variable que indicará si el número es primo
            boolean primo = true;
            // obtener el número del vector en i
            int numero = vector[i];
            
            // si es menor o igual a uno no hacer nada y continuar
            if(numero <= 1) continue;
            
            // dividir el número entre todos los números
            // entre 2 y numero -1 para comprobar si es primo
            for(int j = 2; j < numero; j++){
                
                // si el número es divisible (residuo igual a cero) 
                // significa que no es primo
                if(numero % j == 0) {
                    // se indica que primo es falso
                    primo = false;
                    // se rompe el ciclo
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            // se imprime el resultado de primo
            if(primo) System.out.println("es primo : " + numero);
        }
        
    }
```